# How to detect function overloading in an input file by looking at the Clang AST representation

Tags: c++, clang, clang++

I am writing a tool that uses Clang as a front-end.  While traversing the Clang AST, I want to know if an instance of `FunctionDeclaration` is overloaded with another in the user input; that is, I want to know if the input program has an overloaded function.  Looking in `llvm-clang/source/tools/clang/include/clang/AST/Decl.h` at `class FunctionDecl` and elsewhere and also in `DeclBase.h`, I do not see how to do it.

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I am facing the same problem.

Comment: I just put every function having a body into a map from name to function and then if two functions have the same name I check if both have a body I report an error.

Comment: Okay thanks, I think I will take a similar approach.